# Integrating Google Plus SignIn in android shows unexpected dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-plus, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate google plus signIn in my android app.All API calls as well as code is working fine. But am getting an unexpected dialog though I have nothing in my layout xml.

Also, I have done all the prerequisite integration process from google's developers site.

Below is my code:

```
public class GooglePlusActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "GooglePlusMainActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private GoogleApiClient mPlusClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_plus);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mPlusClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    signIn();

}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mPlusClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
    finish();
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount currentPerson = result.getSignInAccount();

        if (currentPerson != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GooglePlusActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("socialuserID", currentPerson.getId());
                intent.putExtra("userEmail", currentPerson.getEmail());
                intent.putExtra("userFname", currentPerson.getDisplayName());
                startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Logcat? What unexpected dialog?

Comment: @GaurawYadav I have attached screenshot showing that dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Follow carefully through Google Integration Guide:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

You need to:

- generate and add to /app directory the google-services.json file
- in project's gradle add dependency:

  ```
  dependencies { 
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
  }
  ```
- in app gradle add plugin:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  ```

  and dependencies:

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
  }
  ```
- in Activity's onCreate create GoogleApiClient:

  ```
  GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
          .requestEmail()
          .build();

  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
          .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
          .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
          .build();
  ```

  Your Activity need to implement GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener (Android Studio will notice you about that)
- in layout add Sign In button:

  ```
  <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
  android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  ```
- attach onClickListener to the button:

  ```
  findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
  ```

  this will add implementation of View.OnClickListener to activity
- create onClick method:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
   }
  }
  ```
- create signIn method:

  ```
  private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
  }
  ```
- add method to catch event

  ```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
  }
  ```
- and finally handle SignIn

  ```
  private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Log.d(TAG, "authenticated " + acct.getDisplayName() + " " + acct.getEmail());
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        Log.d(TAG, "unAuthenticated");
    }
  }
  ```

Above example works without white dialog.

You can refer to Google Sample at: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java if you have any doubts

Comment: Appreciate it @Fill , but the same I have implemented as you can see in my code, only the difference is I haven't added google signIn button . But the  issue still persist , is it some sort of problem occurring because of the json generated through google console?